# Why is adl preferring the 'boost::range_detail::operator|' over the local 'operator|'?

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup, boost-range

I'm trying to write an `operator|` for my template class `boo` and everything works out fine until the template class is a boost range type - like in the example a `boost::range::filter_range` - adl prefers the `boost::range_detail::operator|(SinglePassRange& r, const replace_holder<T>)` over the local one.

Can anyone explain why adl is preferring the overload from the boost this detailed namespace over the local namespace?

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>

namespace local
{
    template<typename T>
    struct boo {};

    // this overload is not prefered when T is a boost::range::xxx_range
    template<typename T, typename U>
    auto operator|(boo<T>, U)
    {
        return false;
    }

    void finds_local_operator_overload()
    {
        std::vector<int> xs;

        // works like expected and calls local::operator|
        auto f = boo<decltype(xs)>{} | xs;
    }

    void prefers_boost_range_detail_replaced_operator_overload_instead_of_local_operator()
    {
        std::vector<int> xs;
        // compiler error because it tries to call 'boost::range_detail::operator|'
        auto filtered = xs | boost::adaptors::filtered([](auto &&x){ return x % 2; });
        auto f = boo<decltype(filtered)>{} | xs;
    }
```

}

clang error (msvc reports almost the same):

```
/xxx/../../thirdparty/boost/1.60.0/dist/boost/range/value_type.hpp:26:70: error: no type named 'type' in
      'boost::range_iterator<local::boo<boost::range_detail::filtered_range<(lambda at
      /xxx/Tests.cpp:221:49), std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, void>'
    struct range_value : iterator_value< typename range_iterator<T>::type >
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/xxx/../../thirdparty/boost/1.60.0/dist/boost/range/adaptor/replaced.hpp:122:40: note: in instantiation of template class
      'boost::range_value<local::boo<boost::range_detail::filtered_range<(lambda at
      /xxx/Tests.cpp:221:49), std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >' requested
      here
               BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME range_value<SinglePassRange>::type>& f)
                                       ^
/xxx/Tests.cpp:222:37: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into
      function template 'operator|' [with SinglePassRange = local::boo<boost::range_detail::filtered_range<(lambda at
      /xxx/Tests.cpp:221:49), std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >]
        auto f = boo<decltype(filtered)>{} | xs;
```

Comment: Both operator should be considered. but I suppose the boost's one is more specialized that your's.

Comment: Why is the `boost::range_detail::replace_holder` template functions considered? There is no argument that opens the boost namespace. 
There is only the template 'T' that is from the boost namespace . 
And if there is a good reason for considering it, why aren't the other boost range holder template functions not considered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the rules of [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl),
namespace and classes added in the set for overloads for `boo<decltype(filtered)>{} | xs` are `local` (for `boo`), `boost::range_detail` (for `decltype(filtered)`) and `std` (for `std::vector<int>` `xs`).

We have in particularity:

(As you expect, your's in `local`

```
template<typename T, typename U> auto operator|(boo<T>, U);
```

and )

a problematic one in `boost::range_detail`:

```
template <class SinglePassRange>
replaced_range<const SinglePassRange>
operator|(
    const SinglePassRange&,
    const replace_holder<typename range_value<SinglePassRange>::type>&);
```

So we have the non deduced `range_value<boo<decltype(filtered)>>::type` which provokes a hard error. (The method is unfortunately not SFINAE friendly to be removed from overload set).

Error happens before [overload_resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution).

Comment: There seems to be some ambiguity in the cppreference documented 'class template specialization': in this case, `boo<decltype(filtered)>` is clearly not a specialization, it is a class template _instantiation_.

Comment: @xtofl it's a specialization (well, *simple-template-id* that names a specailization), its use in a program may cause an (implicit) instantiation as per 14.7.1[temp.inst]